# Gremlin check if a Set attribute contains a value

Tags: java, set, gremlin, tinkerpop

I have a vertex with a Set attribute and a graph traversal e.g.

```
graph.traversal().V().hasId(id)
```

the returned vertex has a set attribute and I need to check if it contains a specific value

Comment: So `V()` returns a `Set<>`?

Comment: vertex that has a set attribute

Comment: Just provide a minimal example of what you're doing.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you storing an actual Java `Set` as a property or using `Cardinality.set` to create multi-properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.has("myProp", __.unfold().is("myVal"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be used to check if the value is contained in a set or list

```
g.V().has('MyProp',__unfold().is(within('someValue','SomeOtherOptionalValue'))
```